# Installing an OS onto a disk which has reallocated sectors

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, smart

I have an SSD which SMART says has 7 reallocated sectors. However, SMART also says the disk is OK.

Is it all right to install a new OS on it? I am guessing that it would be fine seeing as the sectors are reallocated, the installer will just not 'see them' and will go ahead with the install, but I want to confirm.

Comment: When you get to around 70% of the drive being re-allocated SMART will indicate the disk is failing and it's then the time to worry about the stability of the drive.

Comment: Thank you, so seeing as it's under 0.01% of the drive I probably shouldn't be too concerned unless they start to increase rapidly.